# Cell phone frequencies in Nicaragua

Tags: cellphones, nicaragua

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a definitive reference guide to cell phone standards by country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/394/is-there-a-definitive-reference-guide-to-cell-phone-standards-by-country)

As far as I know, the Nicaraguan cell phone system is on the GSM standard and has two major providers, Claro and Movistar. But what frequencies are used by those two providers' networks? What requirements must a phone meet to work in Nicaragua?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this site](http://allworldcellphones.com/gsm-frequencies-list.htm), GSM 1900.  According to Wikipedia, Movistar uses GSM 850/1900.  Therefore, if you are coming from the USA, chances are very good that your phone will work (especially if you have a [multi-band phone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-band), which are very common these days).  Since there are four main frequency bands in GSM, if you have a quad-band phone (*e.g.*, the iPhone), it will likely work everywhere in the world.  As [Rory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/243/rory-mccann) mentioned in the other answer, if you want to actually get a Claro or Movistar SIM card, you are going to need to have an unlocked phone.  If, on the other hand, your current provider has an international roaming plan, your phone should work fine.  If you plan on taking the latter option, I suggest you call up your current provider, tell them the model of your phone, and they should be able to tell you if it will work in Nicaragua and how much your calls will cost.

Answer (score 3):

Are you coming from the USA? If so you may be used to the USA system with multiple incompatible networks. However in most of the rest of the world, all mobile phone networks are GSM, and are interoperable and work on the same frequency. (see this question [Is there a definitive reference guide to cell phone standards by country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/394/is-there-a-definitive-reference-guide-to-cell-phone-standards-by-country) ), so *usually* all you need is an unlocked GSM phone. **NB:** I have no knowledge of Nicaragua, merely extrapolating.